# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable while trying to access a reversed range

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to run this code to get the tic-tac diagonal winner in jupyter notebook .

```
game = [[1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 1]]


cols = list(reversed(range(len(game))))
rows = range(len(game))

for idx in rows:
    print(idx, cols[idx])
```

The Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-250-b70a53369f72> in <module>
      6 
      7 
----> 8 cols = list(reversed(range(len(game))))
      9 rows = range(len(game))
     10 

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: As detailed in the answer, your posted code is not sufficient to produce the error you claim.

Answer (score 1):

You've shadowed the name `list` somewhere. Search your code for a line that looks like:

```py
list = <something>
```

You can easily diagnose by inserting a line just before your `cols = list(...)`:

```py
print(type(list))
```

If you haven't shadowed this, you'll see `<class 'type'>` appear on your command line. I'm betting instead you'll see `<class 'list'>` (or something else entirely)

Take pains not to shadow built-ins, because it causes errors like this.

Comment: As an aside `lst` is a commonly-used name for a generic list, since `list` is a bad idea.

Comment: I must have created a list named list and deleted the code. Now that I have deleted all the variable from the memory I can run the code and when I type print(type(list)) then I get <class 'type'>. Thanks a lot, Adam.